# If statements in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a small code where if the day of the month is 01 I need to do some operations.

```
echo %Date:~0,10%
SET day=%Date:~0,2%
echo %day%

IF %day%==01
(echo success)
```

It's showing the syntax command is incorrect.
Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Open a command prompt window, tyape `if /?` and read the help text carefully! There are some good and bad syntax examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo %Date:~0,10%
SET day=%Date:~0,2%
echo %day%

IF %day%==01 (echo success)
```

or

```
echo %Date:~0,10%
SET day=%Date:~0,2%
echo %day%

IF %day%==01 (
  echo success
)
```

With if command the command that should be executed after the condition should be on the same line or a opening bracket on the same line